# how to write Junit test case for spring boot rest controller which uses mongodb for data persist

Tags: mongodb, junit, spring-boot-test

I am trying to write junit test cases for my spring boot controller.

I have two API getUser and AddUser, these APIs talk to mongotemplate over dao to put the data in mongo DB and get the data from  mongo DB.

I have  MongoConfiguration class(it has server address, port password etc)  is configured @Value by property file which is configured through **@PropertySource**

mongo template is created with details reading from **@Autowired** mongoconfig class.

when I write junit test case and tested,  it was using actual mongoDB which was configured for all developers through standard properties file, so for my testing I want to use some kind of embedded mongo to mock the mongo db template

So how to avoid using my actual mongodb during my junit test cases

This is my below code which is working with actual db

```
public class UserControllerTest extends AbstractTest {
   @Override
   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      super.setUp();
   }
   @Test
   public void createProduct() throws Exception {
       User user =  new User();
       user.setName("UnitTest");

      String inputJson = super.mapToJson(user);
      String uri = "/iot/user/createuser";
      MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(uri)
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
         .content(inputJson)).andReturn();

      int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
      assertEquals(201, status);

   }
}
```